# Unable to view GWT 2.0.1 application in IE8

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-8

I'm creating an application using GWT 2.0.1; it complies 6 computations and runs well in all browsers except IE8, it shows a blank page( but can be viewed in IE8 compatibility mode) .
 When I add the line in my gwt.xml
<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie8" / >
 it compiles just 1 permutation  and the application displays fine in IE8. However if I add the line
<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie8,gecko,gecko1_8,safari,opera" />
it compiles all permutations, but the application still cannot be viewed in IE8 but runs properly in all other browsers.

Is there any other method to ensure my application will run in all browsers ?

Comment: A current work-around we've used is adding the doctype :- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/DTD/strict.dtd">

and the line :   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" / >
in the head tag. 
Although this is a workaround and runs out web application in the IE7 emulator mode in IE8, its not a real solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are looking for a nice solution, you have to insert this line :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5,6,8,9" >
```

in your `.html` file (the host page)

This will ensure that your page is compatible with *ascendant* IEs...

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/IE8Support) besides setting the proper user agent you have to add the following meta tag to enforce IE8 standards mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once and the problem was that the HTML page that bootstrapped the GWT JavaScript had an unmatched HTML tag. This didn't cause a problem in Firefox or Chrome, but IE just displayed a blank page. Try verifying your HTML using an HTML Validator. The W3C validator is a the cannonical service.

http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but, we already tried the validator shows 0 errors and some warnings and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie8,gecko,gecko1_8,safari,opera" / >
```

Comment: It seems this will just set user.agent to "opera", since each next line overrides previous..

Answer (score 0):

Try diffing the generated permutations for IE8 when you use `<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie8" / >` and when you use `<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie8,gecko,gecko1_8,safari,opera" />`. If they are different, you might get some clue to take forward your investigation. Use fiddler or IE developer tools to monitor and compare the names of *.cache.js files being loaded in each case.